# Converting Jats XML to LaTeX

Tags: conversion, xml

I need to convert Jats XML to LaTeX.

Jats means Journal Article Tag Suite and it's a XML format to Scientific publications. Other important XML schemas like SciELO Publishing Schema derive from it.

I'm looking for an open source project for it.

Comment: Have a look at `xmltex`. You would probably have to write a format file for it to map the Jats markup to LaTeX markup.

Answer (score 5):

I have developed a small app written in Java for JATS to LaTeX conversion. It is open source: https://github.com/Vitaliy-1/JATS2LaTeX